# Tools to save, tag and share images with clients/team?

Tags: tools, screenshot

When you are doing visual research, what tools do you use to save, tag and share images or screenshots with clients/team? Do you know other tools than Little Snapper?

Answer (score 1):

I use a combination of Evernote and Dropbox or Google Drive.

[Evernote](http://evernote.com/) works to keep notes and visual reference together in a shareable 'notebook'. It also has a rather good ability to search the text in your images. This comes in handy when I take notes directly on my sketches (which I capture with my camera phone directly into Evernote).

[Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/plans) / [Drive](http://drive.google.com/start) (depending on the preference of the team/client) is less for brainstorming and more about just sharing files. They both do a great job of keeping local directories synced between team members. If you just want to toss a bunch of images into a folder and know that everyone else will see them too, this is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Pixlr is a fantastic tool to grab,edit and share pictures beetween my clients/team.

You can use the grabber if you want to click and share in firefox or chrome or use their image sharing service http://imm.io/

http://pixlr.com/grabber

Plus, now it has been acquired by Autodesk